# Java: two digit Lottery

Tags: java

I  am  working on  this lottery code but  experiencing an endless  run. i would  appreciate  pointing out what  may be  wrong  with the  code and  how  to go  about rectifying it. Thank you.  The  question is "to generate a lottery of a two digit number. The two digits in the number are distinct. (Hint: Generate the first digit. Use a loop to continuously generate the second digit until it is different from the first digit.)

```
public class Lottery1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create  Scanner
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        //generate 2 digit random  lottery  number
        int lottery = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        // TODO code application logic here
        //generate first and second digit of lottery
        int lotterydigit1 = lottery / 10;
        int lotterydigit2 = lottery % 10;
        while (lotterydigit2 != lotterydigit1) {
            lotterydigit2 = lottery % 10;
        }

        //prompt user for guess digits 
        System.out.print("Enter two Digit  number:");
        int guess = s.nextInt();
        int guessdigit1 = guess / 10;
        int guessdigit2 = guess % 10;

        // compare lottery and 
        if (guessdigit1 == lotterydigit1 && guessdigit2 == lotterydigit2) {
            System.out.println("You  just won $10,0000");
        } else if (guessdigit1 == lotterydigit2 && guessdigit2 == lotterydigit1) {
            System.out.println("You  have  won $5,000");
        } else if (guessdigit1 == lotterydigit1
                || guessdigit1 == lotterydigit2
                || guessdigit2 == lotterydigit1
                || guessdigit2 == lotterydigit2) {
            System.out.println("You have won $1,000");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You  have  not won anything");
        }
        System.out.println("lottery number is" + " " + lottery + " and     your  guess is" + guess);
    }

}
```

Comment: Try putting `lottery = (int)(Math.random()*100);` inside of your while loop - you're never changing what you set it to!

Comment: there are compilation errors in your code and formatting it properly would be helpful too

Comment: `while (lotterydigit2!=lotterydigit1)` surely also wants to be `while (lotterydigit2==lotterydigit1)`? You only want to change `lotterydigit2` if they are similar.

Answer (score 0):

You want them to be different so change

```
   while (lotterydigit2!=lotterydigit1){
              lotterydigit2 = lottery%10;
                }
```

to

```
while (lotterydigit2==lotterydigit1){
          lotterydigit2 = lottery%10;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (lotterydigit2!=lotterydigit1){
      lotterydigit2 = lottery%10;
}
```

lotterydigit2 has always the same value. If lottery%10 is != to lotterydigit1 in the first run, it won't get out of the loop because you're not changing anything.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your problem is in your hint:

> Use a loop to continuously generate the second digit until it is different from the first digit.

And you don't generate anything in your loop:

```
while (lotterydigit2 != lotterydigit1) {
    lotterydigit2 = lottery % 10;
}
```

You also have the condition wrong - "until it is different" means "while they are the same".

I would recommend to generate two digits separately:

```
int lotterydigit1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
int lotterydigit2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
while (lotterydigit2 == lotterydigit1) {
    lotterydigit2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
}
```